Why does the acidity order (CH₄ < NH₃ < H₂O < HF) follow the bond strength order (C-H < N-H < O-H < F-H) when stronger bonds should resist breaking?
I'm trying to understand the relationship between bond strength and acidity in the series CH₄, NH₃, H₂O, and HF. The bond strength order is C-H < N-H < O-H < F-H, meaning the F-H bond is the strongest. However, the acidity order follows the same trend (CH₄ < NH₃ < H₂O < HF).
This seems counterintuitive to me because I would expect stronger bonds to resist breaking and thus be less likely to lose a proton (H⁺), which should result in lower acidity. While I understand that the stability of the conjugate base is a key factor in determining acidity, shouldn't the bond dissociation energy also significantly influence the acidity?
Could someone clarify why the acidity order follows the bond strength order, and how bond strength is reconciled with acidity in this context?

From Wikipedia: "[bond dissociation energy] can be defined as the standard enthalpy change when A−B is cleaved by homolysis to give fragments A and B, which are usually radical species." This has very little to do with acidity, which is a heterolytic cleavage. A strongly overlapped bond (like in H-F) is difficult to separate into two atoms of H and F, but not so difficult to separate into a proton and fluoride.

Thank you sir, that helped me.
